# In Go, deleting an entry of a map of pointers causes memory leak?

Tags: dictionary, pointers, go, memory-leaks

first timer here,

The first **NOTE** in [SliceTricks](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/SliceTricks) suggests that there is a potential memory leak problem when cutting or deleting elements in a slice of pointers.

Is the same true for a map? For example: https://play.golang.org/p/67cN0JggWY

Should we nil the entry before deleting from map? Like so:

```
m["foo"] = nil
```

What if we simply *clear* the map?

```
m = make(map[string]*myStruct)
```

Will the garbage collector still pick it up?

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are no  leaks. We shouldn't nil the entry.

Answer (score 8):

### Checking the sources

Although this is not documented anywhere, checking the sources: [`runtime/hashmap.go`](https://golang.org/src/runtime/hashmap.go), `mapdelete()` function:

```
558 func mapdelete(t *maptype, h *hmap, key unsafe.Pointer) {
        // ...
600             memclr(k, uintptr(t.keysize))
601             v := unsafe.Pointer(uintptr(unsafe.Pointer(b)) + dataOffset + bucketCnt*uintptr(t.keysize) + i*uintptr(t.valuesize))
602             memclr(v, uintptr(t.valuesize))
        // ...
618 }
```

As you can see, storage for both the key (line #600) and the value (line #602) are cleared / zeroed.

This means if any of the key or value was a pointer, or if they were values of complex types containing pointers, they are zeroed and therefore the pointed objects are no longer referenced by the internal data structures of the map, so there is no memory leak here.

When there is no more reference to a complete `map` value, then the complete memory area of the `map` will be garbage collected, and all the pointers included in keys and values are also not held anymore by the map; and if no one else has reference to the pointed objects, they will be garbage collected properly.

### Constructing an example to prove this

We can also construct a test code which proves this without examining the sources:

```
type point struct {
    X, Y int
}

var m = map[int]*point{}

func main() {
    fillMap()
    delete(m, 1)
    runtime.GC()
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    fmt.Println(m)
}

func fillMap() {
    p := &point{1, 2}
    runtime.SetFinalizer(p, func(p *point) {
        fmt.Printf("Finalized: %p %+v\n", p, p)
    })
    m[1] = p
    fmt.Printf("Put in map: %p %+v\n", p, p)
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/X-eRlTjU35)):

```
Put in map: 0x1040a128 &{X:1 Y:2}
Finalized: 0x1040a128 &{X:1 Y:2}
map[]
```

What does this do? It creates a `*Point` value (pointer to a struct), puts it in the map, and registers a function that *should* be called when this pointer becomes unreachable (using [`runtime.SetFinalizer()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#SetFinalizer)), and then deletes the entry containing this pointer. Then we call [`runtime.GC()`](https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#GC) to "force" an immediate garbage collection. I also print the map at the end just to make sure the whole map is not garbage collected due to some optimization.

The result? We see the registered function gets called, which proves the pointer was removed from the map as the result of the `delete()` call, because (since we had no other references to it) it was eligible for garbage collection.

Comment: It's not clear from the snippet of code you posted what prevents value pointers with references elsewhere from being GC'd, e.g. if you add `v := m[1]` on the line following the `fillMap()` call, and then `fmt.Println(v)` after the map entry has been deleted, the struct prints as expected and isn't zeroed out. It makes sense why this would be useful but it's not clear from the `mapdelete` code snippet why it's not zeroed out.

Comment: @ashgromnies I'm not sure I understand what you want to say. If there is any reference to an object that is reachable, it cannot be gc'd. If the map has the _only_ reference and it is deleted from the map, then it is eligible for gc.

Answer (score 7):

No, there will not be any memory leaks when deleting from a map.

In case of slices, since a slice actually uses an underlying array, as long as the slice exists - even if it uses just one slot in that array - the pointer items inside the array can not get garbage collected.

"[A slice describes a piece of an array](https://blog.golang.org/slices)" which implies the array needs to be there for the slice to exist and can not get collected by GC; as long as some code is pointing at the slice.